# Cannot Group rows in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a little trifle in Excel-VBA. I had 114000 rows of data each with a unique flag. I wanted to group them using Excel>Data>Group function. I recorded a macro and based on that wrote this code:

```
Sub Macro2()


Dim i As Double


With ActiveSheet.Outline
    .AutomaticStyles = False
    .SummaryRow = xlAbove
    .SummaryColumn = xlLeft
End With

For i = 1 To 141163

If Range("B" & i).Value = 9 Then
Rows("i:i").Select
Selection.Rows.Group

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I am getting run time error 1005 at `Rows("i:i").Select`. Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Rows(i & ":" & i).Group Selecting is unneeded and makes your code go slower. Just an FYI. Always try to avoid the Select method. Very rare cases are needed for an actual select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surrounding with quotes takes the literal value "i" not the variable definition. Try the following:

```
Rows(i & ":" & i).Select
```

Comment: Hi there, I had 1 more problem. When I try to group it based on 9 then 7 then 3 in the formula Range("B" & i).Value = 9/7/3; all of them get grouped in one. I want separate groups for 9,7,3. Please help!

Comment: hello Amit, its best to start a new question with all the details you have and the vector of numbers you are using. There isnt enough space in the comments for me to understand the issue and what is causing it